# Python Sockets send an integer value greater than 127 as a single byte

Tags: python, sockets

I am using Python 3 and I wish to send an integer greater than 127 as a single byte. As expected, I can't do that with the chr() function as this function converts it into 2 bytes. When I use str() it converts it to 3 separate bytes that I don't want. 
I have tried but I can't seem to get any solution.

Comment: What function are you using to send a string? I’d think it would take bytes instead. (`bytes([128])`)

Comment: there is some message text as well. So ultimately I have to append it to a string. I cant figure out how to append for example 160 as a single byte.

Comment: You would also convert the string to bytes first, using `str.encode`. What function are you using to send a string?

Comment: I am using socket.send() function from python sockets library. this function takes a string

Comment: `socket.send` doesn’t take a string in Python 3. It takes bytes. Can you show your code?

Comment: Oh yes. Pardon me. It takes bytes. I did use the encode() function to send that. but I stil get two bytes if I use chr() function and str gives three bytes each for 1 6 and 0.

Comment: Okay, well, you’ll want to concatenate `bytes([x])` after encoding, not before. Can you show your code?

Comment: Sure. Here you go: [link](https://pastebin.com/kLypBDmK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should try to keep byte-oriented operations done on bytestrings (`bytes`) and text-oriented (or at least USV-oriented) operations done on strings (`str`). So instead of trying to construct your message as a string for a single final encode:

```
message_identifier =  chr(50)
message_name = 'Hello '
message_data_size = '160'.encode().decode() # clueless here

frame = (message_identifier + message_name + (message_data_size)) # don't know what to do with message_data_size

byt = frame.encode()
```

encode when the logic passes the boundary from text to bytes:

```
message_identifier = bytes([50])  # or b'\x32', or b'2'
message_name = 'Hello '
message_data_size = bytes([160])

frame = message_identifier + message_name.encode('utf-8') + message_data_size
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you for such a perfect explanation mate! :)